# What is correct phrase for the relationship with my son's father/mother in law

Tags: kinship-terms

What is the correct phrase for the relationship between me and my son's father/mother in law?

Comment: Not English (but many English speakers use it), there is a Yiddish word, [*machatonim*](http://www.thejc.com/judaism/jewish-words/machatonim) that means the inlaws of your child.

Comment: I doubt that there is one. See *[Paucity of words for relationships](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51616)* and *[Is there an accepted rule for naming all of our various distant relatives?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1605)*

Comment: Apologies, @bib, but I would tend to think that the only English speakers who use it are Yiddish speakers or cultural Jews.  Although I, who am neither, nevertheless use certain Yiddish words and phrases that have leaked into common use.  And as a German-speaker I can understand Yiddish better than most other English-speakers.  So maybe we should adopt *machatonim*!  I'd vote for it!

Comment: hostility? amity? indifference?

Comment: @Oldcat?  What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: since you have no relation to your son's father in law by blood or marriage, then the definition of "emotional connection" presumably applies. So I suggested some possible emotional connections.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist If we do, then we get into the arguments about the various transliterations to English spelling.

Comment: @bib - See? The fun is neverending!

Comment: Spanish has __consuegros__. I have seen this question before, and always suggest we adopt __cross-laws__. (_Machatonim_ enters Yiddish from Hebrew: _chatan_ is the word for groom.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in your question.

There is no special term in English for a person's child's parents-in-law.

They are your son's parents-in-law.

Now, this is not to say that English wouldn't be enriched to have such a term, but it doesn't and there we are.  It also doesn't have terms to distinguish between the flavors of aunts and uncles, and a few others that do exist in other languages.

Comment: I'm not sure which aunt/uncle flavors you're referring to but we do have great aunts, etc.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I think Cyberherbalist is referring to the difference between "blood" aunts/uncles (parents' siblings) and "marriage" aunts/uncles (parents' siblings' spouses).

Comment: Yes, exactly, @starsplusplus.  In Swedish, there are also distinctions between one's mother's and father's brothers: marbror and farbror.  Both would be biological, of course.

Comment: Or your son's wife/spouse's parents.

Comment: Latin distinguishes "avunculus" from "patruua".material versus paternal uncle, and likewise, for aunts, "matertera" and "abita".

Comment: And then Chinese distinguishes older sister from younger sister, older brother from younger brother.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't realized when we had daughters, that I would also be gifted with sons when they married.  My affection for their parents is beyond the tepid description "my son-in-laws parents".  "Affinity sister/brother" is a much better term, as connected by choice albeit our children's choice. so...this holiday season I plan to introduce Kay as "my affinity sister who is Dave's (my son-in-law's) mother".

Comment: Ps I knew they would marry men but never realized how much a part of our family they would become, and bring delightful family with them.