# what to call same level descendants?

Tags: kinship-terms, equivalence

sisters and brothers are siblings.

sisters and brothers from different sibling parents are cousins.

what do you call after cousin? or in general, same level descendants, is there word for that?

Comment: They are still cousins.

Comment: oh, good to know. so cousin is general term? thanks for answer, I appreciate if you post it as answer so I can accept. btw English is not my mother language.

Comment: Another (more precise) system is "third cousin four times removed" and so on.  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin

Comment: Do you mean the children of your parents' cousins? They're second cousins.

Comment: This is a common question here. To start, look at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/is-there-an-accepted-rule-for-naming-all-of-our-various-distant-relatives-kinsh and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51616/paucity-of-words-for-relationships/

Comment: @GEdgar  The word "cousin" can be used specifically to mean a "first cousin", but it is often extended, without modification, to mean a more distant cousin - it depends on the context. At the extreme, British people will sometimes refer to an entire population as "our American/Australian cousins". Often this is in an ironical sense to highlight some predisposition which is different to our own e.g. "you can rely on our American cousins to have forgotten how to make a nice cup of tea, but they know more about coffee than we do".

Comment: I think the extended use of "cousin" also includes other generations, not just the same generation.

Comment: @GEdgar A "third cousin four times removed" would be a pretty distant relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A child of a sibling of your parents is a *first cousin*.
A grandchild of a sibling of your grandparents is a *second cousin*.
And so on for cousins of the same generation as you.

For cousins of a different generation, you use *removed*.  So if a cousin is one generation different - in either direction - they are *once removed*.  Two generations - *twice removed* and so on.

The simple word [*cousin*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cousin&t=crmtb01), used alone, covers all of these relatives.